# Python: regex pattern fails after being split into multiple lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I have a regex pattern that works fine if I write it in a single line.

For instance, the pattern work if I do the following:

```
MAIN_TREE_START_STRING_PATTERN = (
    r"\*{3}\s+\bTotal Things\b:\s+(?P<number_of_things>\d+)"
)
compiled_pattern = re.compile(MAIN_TREE_START_STRING_PATTERN, flags=re.X)
match = compiled_pattern.match(string="*** Total Things: 348, abcdefghi ***")

if match:
    print("Success")
else:
    print("Failed")
```

But if I changed the regex pattern to be a multiline string, and using the `VERBOSE` flag, it doesn't work.

```
MAIN_TREE_START_STRING_PATTERN = r"""
\*{3}\s+\bTotal Things\b:\s+
(?P<number_of_things>\d+)
"""
compiled_pattern = re.compile(MAIN_TREE_START_STRING_PATTERN)
match = compiled_pattern.match(string="*** Total Things: 348, abcdefghi ***")

if match:
    print("Success")
else:
    print("Failed")
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong during the multiline pattern declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using re.VERBOSE and you have to match the space explicitly in that case

```
import re

MAIN_TREE_START_STRING_PATTERN = r"""
\*{3}\s+\bTotal[ ]Things\b:\s+
(?P<number_of_things>\d+)
"""
compiled_pattern = re.compile(MAIN_TREE_START_STRING_PATTERN, re.VERBOSE)
match = compiled_pattern.match(string="*** Total Things: 348, abcdefghi ***")

if match:
    print("Success")
else:
    print("Failed")
```

Comment: What other things need to be declared explicitly when using verbose? Do you have any docs where I can verify that?

Comment: @Jacobo The documentation about re.VERBOSE is at [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE).

Answer (score 1):

Line breaks inside multiline string literals are also part of the resulting string. The additional line breaks are most probably the reason why you regular expression no longer works.

To get rid of the line breaks, you can simply define multiple strings that get automatically concatenated by Python:

```py
MAIN_TREE_START_STRING_PATTERN = (
    r"\*{3}\s+\bTotal Things\b:\s+"
    r"(?P<number_of_things>\d+)"
)
```